# Transform Array of object changing by time using map, filter and reduce

Tags: javascript

I have a `reportsList` array include for example 1000 `report` object like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 69,
        "userId": 8,
        "emotion": {
            "id": "worried",
            "name": "Worried Face",
            "colons": ":worried:",
            "emoticons": [],
            "native": "",
            "skin": null,
            "unified": "1f61f"
        },
        "title": "Ut voluptatem in.",
        "date": "2018-08-01"
    },
    {
        "id": 119,
        "userId": 2,
        "emotion": {
            "id": "heart_eyes",
            "name": "Smiling Face with Heart-Shaped Eyes",
            "colons": ":heart_eyes:",
            "emoticons": [],
            "skin": null,
            "native": ""
        },
        "title": "Maiores inventore sapiente optio est et.",
        "date": "2018-08-01"
    },
    {
        "id": 187,
        "userId": 18,
        "emotion": {
            "id": "laughing",
            "name": "Smiling Face with Open Mouth and Tightly-Closed Eyes",
            "colons": ":laughing:",
            "emoticons": [
                ":>",
                ":->"
            ],
            "native": "",
            "skin": null,
            "unified": "1f606"
        },
        "title": "Voluptatibus qui fugit omnis cumque sapiente.",
        "date": "2018-08-01"    },
    {
        "id": 256,
        "userId": 20,
        "emotion": {
            "id": "white_frowning_face",
            "name": "White Frowning Face",
            "colons": ":white_frowning_face:",
            "emoticons": [],
            "skin": null,
            "native": "☹️",
            "unified": "2639-fe0f"
        },
        "title": "Dolor dolores et ut omnis aperiam.",
        "date": "2018-08-01"
    },
    {
        "id": 519,
        "userId": 1,
        "emotion": {
            "id": "heart_eyes",
            "name": "Smiling Face with Heart-Shaped Eyes",
            "colons": ":heart_eyes:",
            "emoticons": [],
            "skin": null,
            "native": ""
        },
        "title": "Quis minima odit.",
        "date": "2018-08-01"
    },
    {
        "id": 523,
        "userId": 9,
        "emotion": {
            "id": "laughing",
            "name": "Smiling Face with Open Mouth and Tightly-Closed Eyes",
            "colons": ":laughing:",
            "emoticons": [
                ":>",
                ":->"
            ],
            "native": "",
            "skin": null,
            "unified": "1f606"
        },
        "title": "Hic sed labore exercitationem inventore iusto odio.",
        "date": "2018-08-01"
    }
]
```

Now I'm trying to transform data based on this `reportsList` to value and display them to my Chart using `Chartjs` (My app have `PieChart` and `LineChart`).

But I have some issue that I can't figure out solve.

1. `PieChart` is calculated based on `emotion` Object in each `report` Object of `reportsList`. And for `emotion`, I divided it into three type: `positive`, `negative` and `other`.

My condition of three type like this:

```
reportsList.map(report => {
      const emoji = report.emotion.id;
      if ((emoji === 'smiley')
        || (emoji === 'heart_eyes')
        || (emoji === 'stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye')
        || (emoji === 'laughing')) {

        // positive type

      } else if ((emoji === 'white_frowning_face')
        || (emoji === 'disappointed')
        || (emoji === 'worried')) {

        // negative type

      } else {
        // this is other type
      }
    });
```

The data requirement in this `PieChart` is the quantity of `emotion`, for example:

`emotions = [100, 200, 300]` equivalent to quantity of three emotion types: `positive`, `negative` and `other`. And that is my output I expect

2. `LineChart` is calculated based on `emotion` Object, but It changing by time. I mean, my `LineChart` include 3 line equivalent to three number of emotion: `positive`, `negative` and `other`. And data changing from `2018-06-31` to `2018-09-01`.
   The data requirement in this one is number of emotion object from date range that I given above,

My chart include 3 line so I need three array to full field my chart:

`positiveEmotions = [100, 200, 300, 400]`

`negativeEmotions = [50, 60, 70, 80]`

`otherEmotions = [40, 79, 23, 252]` and all three array equivalent to four months: `6, 7, 8, 9`.

I think `filter`, `map` and `reduce` can handle my problem, but I don't know how to implement this. Please give me some solution or idea. Thanks!

Comment: From where these number `[100,200,300]` comes? Is it something like count? If yes then `positiveEmotions = [100, 200, 300, 400]` what is this?

Comment: @HardikShah Yeah, that number of element in array. 

`emotions = [100, 200, 300]` mean 100 `positiveEmotion`, 200 `negativeEmotion` for 4 month `6, 7, 8, 9`
and `positiveEmotions = [100, 200, 300, 400]` it's `positiveEmotions` for 4 months `6, 7, 8, 9`. For example, in June we have `100`  `positiveEmotion`, July we have `200` and etc,...